# Makefile Error on RUN command only to specific inputs. make run executes properly for other inputs. "make: *** [Makefile:22: run] Error -1073740940"

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm very new to Makefiles. I have a C++ program to find LCS from 2 files and print 1 if it's plagiarised, 0 otherwise. I compile and run it as `./filename FILE1=1.txt FIILE2=2.txt`, getting the path of the files as an input to main (argv,argc) while compilation, which runs successfully.

There seems to be a problem with my Makefile. When I try to execute `make FILE1=1.txt FIILE2=2.txt run`, it runs successfully for some files and returns an error after printing 1(the expected output).

Error:

> PS C:\Users\name\Desktop\folder> make FILE1=1.txt FILE2=2.txt run 1
> make: *** [Makefile:22: run] Error -1073740940

I can't seem to find the error, since the program compiles and runs for all the files.

Makefile:

```
# the compiler: gcc for C, g++ for C++
CC := g++

# compiler flags:
CFLAGS := -Wall -O3

# build target
TARGET := 40220139_detector

FILE1 =
FILE2 = 

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)

run: $(TARGET)
    @./$(TARGET) $(FILE2) $(FILE1)
```

I tried to compile the commands in the makefile in CMD, which complies with all the sample input I have. Also, when I try to change the order of FILES in makefile like "./($TARGET) ($FILE2) ($FILE1)," the error disappears. But the same error occurs for some other file.

I'm running this on Windows 11, VS code:

- make --version
- GNU Make 4.3
- Built for Windows32

My program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

vector<string> readFile(char *filename);
bool detect(vector<string> &f1, vector<string> &f2);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "-1" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    vector<string> f1 = readFile(argv[1]);
    vector<string> f2 = readFile(argv[2]);
    
    if (detect(f1, f2))
    {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "0" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

vector<string> readFile(char *fname)
{
    vector<string> result;
    ifstream file(fname);
    string str;
    while (file >> str)
    {
        
        string new_str = regex_replace(str, regex(R"([^A-Za-z\d])"), "");
        result.push_back(new_str);
    }
    for (string &s : result)
    {
        transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                  [](char c)
                  { return tolower(c); });
    }
   
    return result;
}

bool detect(vector<string> &f1, vector<string> &f2)
{
    int container1, container2;
    float percentage1 = 0.0, percentage2 = 0.0;
    container1 = f1.size();
    container2 = f2.size();
    int count = 0;
    int row, col;
    
    int **matrix = new int *[container1 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < container1 + 1; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[container2];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= container1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= container2; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if (f1[i - 1] == f2[j - 1])
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 1 + matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = container1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = container2; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] > 3)
            {
                row = i;
                col = j;
                while (matrix[row][col] != 0)
                {
                    count++; 
                    row--;
                    col--;
                }
                i = row;
                j = col;
            }
        }
    }    
   
   if (count!=0)
   {
        percentage1 = (float)count / container1;
        percentage2 = (float)count / container2;
        float total1 = percentage1 * 100;
        float total2 = percentage2 * 100;
        if (total1 >= 30 || total2 >= 30)
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please format your pasted text properly so we can see where the newlines etc. are.  the makefile is fine but the example run is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This error: *make: *** [Makefile:22: run] Error -1073740940* means that `make` invoked the program `run`, and it exited with an error code of `-1073740940`.

If you convert that value to hex, you get `0xc0000374`.  If you look up via Google something like `windows exit 0xc0000374` you'll discover that this means there's a heap corruption error in the program.  So, you have a bug in your code.

Comment: Can u pls point me to where I shld be looking to resolve this? I have added the code for ur reference.

Comment: You should break out your debugger, or else add printf statements or some other kind of logging, to verify that you are not accessing memory outside of the size of your arrays.  You may also consider compiling your code with Address Sanitizer (add `-fsanitize=address` to your compile and link lines in your makefile) and see if running your program like that helps.  I don't know if this is supported on Windows, though.